# Why does this Metal shader take 20ms on iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, shader, metal

I wrote a simple point shader with Metal, but it runs really slow with 10K points. All vertices are in an interleaved buffer, they have 4 bytes aligned attributes, but it's still very slow (>70ms CPU and ~20ms GPU). The vertex shader takes around 9ms while the fragment shader takes 12-13ms (!).

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <metal_common>
#include <simd/simd.h>

using namespace metal;

typedef struct {
  float4 position [[ attribute(0) ]];
  float4 color [[ attribute(1) ]];
} Vertex;

typedef struct {
  float4x4 mvpMatrix;
} Uniforms;

typedef struct {
  float4 position [[ position ]];
  float4 color;
  float pointSize [[ point_size ]];
} ColorInOut;

constant float POINT_SIZE = 3.0f;

vertex ColorInOut pointCloudVertex(Vertex vert [[ stage_in ]], constant Uniforms& uniforms [[ buffer(1) ]])
{
  ColorInOut out;
  out.position = uniforms.mvpMatrix * vert.position;
  out.pointSize = POINT_SIZE;
  out.color = vert.color;
  return out;
}

fragment float4 pointCloudFragment(ColorInOut in [[ stage_in ]])
{
  return in.color;
};
```

Leaving CPU aside, which is really weird because I reload the buffers just when needed, do you see anything that could impair the GPU performance?

**UPDATE**:

When I optimized an independent function that was taking a lot of CPU, the GPU usage went down as well. Now the whole shader performs in around 1ms. I am curious to know if the GPU time was so high because it was waiting for the CPU to execute the next cycle.

Comment: Did you use the open gl profiler? that one tells you when gpu is waiting for the cpu

Comment: Using Metal, so OpenGL profiler will not work?